# Callback pattern with a Functor

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to wrap an HttpRequest object (from Cocos2d-x) in my own functor. Everything's working fine except calling the callback passed to my functor. Can you spot the error in the classes below? (I only pasted the relevant parts of the code).

Cloud.hpp:

```
#ifndef Cloud_hpp
#define Cloud_hpp

#include "external/json/document.h"
#include "network/HttpClient.h"

using namespace cocos2d::network;

typedef std::function<void()> CloudCallback;

class Cloud
{
private:
    std::string url { "http://localhost:3000/1.0/" };
    std::string end_point;
    CloudCallback callback;

    std::string getPath();
    void onHttpRequestCompleted(HttpClient *sender, HttpResponse *response);
public:
    Cloud (std::string end_point) : end_point(end_point) {}
    void operator() (CloudCallback callback);
};


#endif /* Cloud_hpp */
```

This is the class that stores the callback passed in the constructor. Here's the implementation:

```
#include "Cloud.hpp"
#include <iostream>

std::string Cloud::getPath()
{
    return url + end_point;
}

void Cloud::operator()(CloudCallback callback)
{
    this->callback = callback;

    std::vector<std::string> headers;

    HttpRequest* request = new (std::nothrow) HttpRequest();
    request->setUrl(this->getPath().c_str());
    request->setRequestType(HttpRequest::Type::GET);
    request->setHeaders(headers);
    request->setResponseCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(Cloud::onHttpRequestCompleted, this));
    HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
    request->release();
}

void Cloud::onHttpRequestCompleted(HttpClient *sender, HttpResponse *response)
{
    this->callback();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, make a simple Http request with the help of a functor, calling like this:

```
Cloud cloud("decks");
cloud([&]() {
    CCLOG("Got the decks");
});
```

I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) as soon as the line

```
this->callback();
```

is called.

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** Now I guess it's something to do with threads. If I remove the HttpRequest and call the callback method passed to the operator() immediately, this works without any problems. Begging for help :-)

Comment: I'm noticing your lambda captures by reference, which means it will be hanging on to references of things in local scope. If those are destroyed by the time the callback is called, you'll have problems. Also, you have a local `Cloud` object - does it outlive the http request? Same thing would happen as the cloud object would be destroyed before the callback is called.

Comment: I guess the Cloud object is destroyed when the httprequest is completed. Memory management is hard in C++.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy You're right. Changing the scope solved the problem. If you can post your comment as an answer, I can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem could be a lifetime issue. Since the http response callback is called asynchronously, some objects may have been destroyed in the meantime. There are two possibilities:

- The `Cloud` object itself is destroyed before the callback is called.
- One or more objects referenced by the lambda (since you're capturing by reference), may have also gone out of scope and been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Cloud::operator()(const CloudCallback &callback)
```

Comment: Same error, somewhere along a file called "functional", on the line "return (*__f_)(_VSTD::forward<_ArgTypes>(__arg)...);".